# Removing string from arraylist

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I need to remove a string from an array list if it does not start with 13. I have read in the data file and each line is read into the ArrayList as a string. The whole line needs to be removed if it does not start with 13. Below shows an example of the data file read in:

```
13 0 150801 00133990 04 04 1 078 2160 999 1 0 1 0 16 04 07 058 0320 061 0127 068 0546 033 0129 048 0586 042 0133 033
13 0 150801 00140480 04 04 1 086 1730 999 1 0 1 0 13 04 06 047 0309 039 0143 032 0772 017 0131 029 0140 037
13 0 150801 00141320 04 04 1 075 1660 999 1 0 1 0 13 03 06 053 0319 036 0132 037 0733 023 0130 026 0134 029
13 0 150801 00144430 01 01 1 071 1570 999 2 0 1 0 04 03 02 040 0567 065
30 0 150801 0015 15 01 0000 0000 0004 0000 0001 0002 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0001 0000 0000 0008 0000
30 0 150801 0015 15 02 0000 0000 0005 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
30 0 150801 0015 15 03 0000 0000 0013 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
30 0 150801 0015 15 04 0000 0000 0021 0000 0000 0001 0001 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0006 0000 0000 0007 0001
21 0 150801 0015 15 01 0002 0001 0005 0004 0003 0001 0001 0000 0000 0000 000973 002 001 010 0001 0001
21 0 150801 0015 15 02 0000 0000 0000 0001 0001 0002 0000 0001 0000 0000 000000 000 000 000 0001 0001
21 0 150801 0015 15 03 0000 0001 0000 0000 0001 0004 0003 0001 0002 0001 000000 000 000 000 0003 0003
21 0 150801 0015 15 04 0000 0002 0009 0008 0007 0002 0006 0004 0000 0000 001252 000 004 012 0001 0003
70 0 150801 0015 15 01 0004 0000 0012 0001 00001400 00000000 00005956 00000476 000412 000000 000897 000076 000042542 000000000 000068665 000005776
70 0 150801 0015 15 02 0005 0000 0000 0000 00001790 00000000 00000000 00000000 000511 000000 000000 000000 000053047 000000000 000000000 000000000
70 0 150801 0015 15 03 0011 0002 0000 0000 00003648 00000625 00000000 00000000 001240 000231 000000 000000 000144378 000026705 000000000 000000000
70 0 150801 0015 15 04 0021 0001 0015 0001 00007334 00000417 00006991 00000449 002203 000086 001172 000080 000235235 000007396 000092708 000006400
13 0 150801 00151590 04 04 1 078 2240 999 1 0 1 0 16 04 07 064 0318 073 0137 071 0545 083 0137 079 0604 066 0133 067
13 0 150801 00155070 01 01 1 078 1760 999 1 0 1 0 13 04 06 059 0324 054 0135 060 0643 022 0133 028 0127 049
13 0 150801 00160780 01 01 1 080 2230 999 1 0 1 0 16 04 07 057 0374 059 0132 059 0724 064 0138 066 0456 052 0138 063
13 0 150801 00162180 04 04 1 063 1820 999 1 0 1 0 16 04 07 058 0264 082 0113 081 0474 079 0113 080 0501 069 0113 070
```

This is what I have written but it doesn't seem like any items are deleted:

```
public class WIMdataReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //Opens the file
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("DATA1month.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String readLine;

        //Creates an ArrayList to store the data line by line
        //Using an ArrayList, which handles dynamic sizing, whereas an array will require a defined size up front, which may not be known.
        List<String> WIMdataList = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Reads file line by line
        while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            WIMdataList.add(readLine);
        }

        //removes items from the arrayList 
        for (int i = 0; i < WIMdataList.size(); i++) {

            if (WIMdataList.get(i).contains("13")) {

            } else {
                WIMdataList.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're removing things from the list, and iterating by index, *iterate backwards*.

Comment: Why not use [`startsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) instead of `contains()`?

Comment: Another thing you can do instead of removing from a `List` is to create a new `List` and add only valid entries to it.

Comment: `Java 8` [`Stream`s and `Filter`](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/) would go nicely here.

Comment: Thanks guys, iterated backwards and it works now. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 5):

If you're removing things from the list, and iterating by index, *iterate backwards*. Otherwise, you never check the item immediately after the one you've just removed, and thus you won't remove it, even if it meets your criteria.

```
for (int i = WIMdataList.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  if (!WIMdataList.get(i).contains("13")) {
    WIMdataList.remove(i);
  }
}
```

Note that repeatedly removing from the middle of an `ArrayList` is inefficient, because all of the subsequent elements have to be moved along each time. You can avoid this by iterating *forwards*, and shifting the elements yourself, and truncating the list at the end:

```
int dst = 0;
for (int src = 0; src < WIMdataList.size(); ++src) {
  if (WIMdataList.get(src).contains("13")) {
    WIMdataList.set(dst++, WIMdataList.get(src));
  }
}
WIMdataList.subList(dst, WIMdataList.size()).clear();
```

But it's easier just to use `removeIf`:

```
WIMdataList.removeIf(s -> !s.contains("13"));
```

Or a filter, to create a new list:

```
List<String> filtered = WIMdataList.stream().filter(s -> s.contains("13")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, of course, just don't add them to the list in the first place.

Comment: but use it with ``startsWith``, not ``contains``.

Comment: @f1sh in OP's code: "`WIMdataList.get(i).contains("13")`". The specific criterion is unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

You can just avoid adding the `Strings` that don't start with a `13` the first time you fill your `ArrayList` adding:

```
if(readLine.startsWith("13")){
    WIMdataList.add(readLine);
}
```

Inside the while that loops through the contents of the file.

---

```
public class WIMdataReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Opens the file
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("DATA1month.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String readLine;

        //Creates an arrayList to store the data line by line
        //Using an ArrayList, which handles dynamic sizing, whereas an array will require a defined size up front, which may not be known.
        List<String> WIMdataList = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Reads file line by line
        while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (readLine.startsWith("13")) {
                WIMdataList.add(readLine);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(WIMdataList);
    }
}
```

You won't iterate the loop twice if you check it beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a shorter manner using `Files` and `Stream`:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("data.txt"))
           .filter(line -> line.startsWith("13"))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The original answer collects to a list, so you probably want to use `.collect(Collectors.toList())` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You should put the if statement in the while loop so that you don't need to iterate through the list again.

```
//Reads file line by line
while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // regex to dertermine if the first "num" is 13
    if (!readLine.matches("^13 .*")) {
        // add to the list if doesn't start with 13
        WIMdataList.add(readLine);
    }
}
```