# ArrayList object matching

Tags: java, android-studio

Please look at Case 300:

I am trying to edit a contact so I'm passing the old contact and the new updated one to delete and add correspondingly
I just end up adding the objects but never deleting

old is an object I receive from a bundle from another activity

Why am I not able to match and delete the object?
Equals and Hash have been generated.

Contact has bitmap and string fields

```
public class Contact implements Parcelable {
    String first, last, company, email, phone, URL, address, nickname, facebook_url, twitter_url, skype, youtube;
    String birthday;
    Bitmap photo;


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Contact contact = (Contact) o;

        if (first != null ? !first.equals(contact.first) : contact.first != null) return false;
        if (last != null ? !last.equals(contact.last) : contact.last != null) return false;
        if (company != null ? !company.equals(contact.company) : contact.company != null)
            return false;
        if (email != null ? !email.equals(contact.email) : contact.email != null) return false;
        if (phone != null ? !phone.equals(contact.phone) : contact.phone != null) return false;
        if (URL != null ? !URL.equals(contact.URL) : contact.URL != null) return false;
        if (address != null ? !address.equals(contact.address) : contact.address != null)
            return false;
        if (nickname != null ? !nickname.equals(contact.nickname) : contact.nickname != null)
            return false;
        if (facebook_url != null ? !facebook_url.equals(contact.facebook_url) : contact.facebook_url != null)
            return false;
        if (twitter_url != null ? !twitter_url.equals(contact.twitter_url) : contact.twitter_url != null)
            return false;
        if (skype != null ? !skype.equals(contact.skype) : contact.skype != null) return false;
        if (youtube != null ? !youtube.equals(contact.youtube) : contact.youtube != null)
            return false;
        if (birthday != null ? !birthday.equals(contact.birthday) : contact.birthday != null)
            return false;
        return photo != null ? photo.equals(contact.photo) : contact.photo == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = first != null ? first.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (last != null ? last.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (company != null ? company.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (phone != null ? phone.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (URL != null ? URL.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (address != null ? address.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (nickname != null ? nickname.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (facebook_url != null ? facebook_url.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (twitter_url != null ? twitter_url.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (skype != null ? skype.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (youtube != null ? youtube.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (birthday != null ? birthday.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (photo != null ? photo.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public Contact(Bitmap photo, String first, String last, String company, String email, String phone, String URL, String address, String nickname, String facebook_url, String twitter_url, String skype, String youtube, String birthday) {
        this.photo = photo;
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.company = company;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;

        this.URL = URL;
        this.address = address;
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.facebook_url = facebook_url;
        this.twitter_url = twitter_url;
        this.skype = skype;
        this.youtube = youtube;
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    protected Contact(Parcel in) {
        photo = in.readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
        first = in.readString();
        last = in.readString();
        company = in.readString();
        email = in.readString();
        phone = in.readString();
        URL = in.readString();
        address = in.readString();
        nickname = in.readString();
        facebook_url = in.readString();
        twitter_url = in.readString();
        skype = in.readString();
        youtube = in.readString();
        birthday = in.readString();


    }

    public static final Creator<Contact> CREATOR = new Creator<Contact>() {
        @Override
        public Contact createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Contact(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Contact[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Contact[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable(photo, flags);
        dest.writeString(first);
        dest.writeString(last);


        dest.writeString(company);
        dest.writeString(email);
        dest.writeString(phone);
        dest.writeString(URL);
        dest.writeString(address);
        dest.writeString(nickname);
        dest.writeString(facebook_url);
        dest.writeString(twitter_url);
        dest.writeString(skype);
        dest.writeString(youtube);
        dest.writeString(birthday);

    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact{" +
                "first='" + first + '\'' +
                ", last='" + last + '\'' +
                ", company='" + company + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                ", URL='" + URL + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", nickname='" + nickname + '\'' +
                ", facebook_url='" + facebook_url + '\'' +
                ", twitter_url='" + twitter_url + '\'' +
                ", skype='" + skype + '\'' +
                ", youtube='" + youtube + '\'' +
                ", birthday=" + birthday +
                ", photo=" + photo +
                '}';
    }
}

public class ContactsHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static String ACTION = "";

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 200:
                if (data.getExtras() != null) {
                    Contact c = (Contact) data.getExtras().get("contactClass");
                    contactArrayList.add(c);
                }
                break;
            case 300:
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                **Contact old =(Contact) extras.getParcelable("old");
                Contact nu = extras.getParcelable("new");

                contactArrayList.add(nu);

               for(int i=0;i<contactArrayList.size();i++)
                   if(contactArrayList.get(i).equals(old))
                       contactArrayList.remove(i);**
                break;
            case 400:
                Contact delete = (Contact) data.getExtras().get("contactDelete");
                    contactArrayList.remove(delete);
                break;

        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts_home);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateNew).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsHome.this, CreateNewContact.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.buttonDisplayContact).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ACTION = "DISPLAY";
                Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsHome.this, DisplayContacts.class);
                intent.putExtra("contactList", contactArrayList);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.buttonDeleteContact).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ACTION = "DELETE";
                Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsHome.this, DisplayContacts.class);
                intent.putExtra("contactList", contactArrayList);
                startActivityForResult(intent,400);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.buttonEditContact).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ACTION = "EDIT";
                Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsHome.this, DisplayContacts.class);
                intent.putExtra("contactList", contactArrayList);
                startActivityForResult(intent,300);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.buttonFinish).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: You can't remove an object from an array during the iteration. You should probably see a "ConcurrentModificationException" when this is running.

Comment: Probably because it's not a valid statement.

Comment: @Karis nope, there's no iterator here.

Comment: What's the *actual* problem you've got here? Is it that you're deleting some but not all things equal to `old`? If that's the case, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46076641/3788176).

Comment: No exceptions were thrown
I've got an old contact that i'm trying to delete but not able to match

Comment: If list has two consecutive elements matching `old`, then only the first will be removed, as you're skipping the second. Three ways to fix: 1) Use an `Iterator` and its `remove()` method. 2) Count `i` down, not up. 3) Decrement `i` when removing. --- If that is not the issue, then `equals()` is likely not implemented correctly, or `old` does not contain the values you think it does. Since you haven't shared any of that, we can't help there.

Comment: Just updated the whole activity code,please check

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Can you please post Contact class with override hashCode and equals???

Comment: In general just generating with your IDE is not enough.

Comment: Posted Contact class

Answer (score -1):

To remove items while iterating a list, you should use an iterator.

For example:

```
Iterator it = contactArrayList.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Object obj = it.next();
    if(obj.equals(old)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does that have to do with code in question not working? Doing it differently with an `Iterator` makes no difference.

Comment: @Andreas, you are right. I assumed too much with too little. Vikhyat, if no exceptions are being thrown, then its probably the `equals` method that is not working or the data in your list does not contain what you expected to contain. As Andreas said, you'll have to provide further details.

Comment: Yup the equals was not implemented. That was the problem. Thanks guys!